# Setting IDENTITY_INSERT off from ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, transactions, identity-column

I am writing a web based importer to import data from one database to another database. Since the data gets loaded into a table that has an identity, I need to enable Identity_Inserts prior to executing my insert statement. I generate the SQL statements I would need to run into a List, and what I would like to do is set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON prior to looping through the commands, then set it to back off once complete. I am going to execute each command one at a time because I want to keep track of which commands failed.

I tried executing SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TABLE NAME] ON before starting the loop, but this isn't working.

How can I accomplish what I am trying to do, or does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Edit your question to include your code.

Comment: Can you post your code?  I can't see any reason why this wouldn't work?

Comment: Are you including the Schema owner in your statement? If the table is not under the dbo schema you will certainly require this to be set. set Identity_Insert xxx.tablename on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/517923/set-identity-insert-already-on-error-message-always-returns-dbo-schema-name

SQL 2k8 BOL states "At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT property set to ON. If a table already has this property set to ON, and a SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON statement is issued for another table, SQL Server returns an error message that states SET IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON and reports the table it is set ON for."

So I guess, you'll need to set it OFF at the end of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Elevated permissions are required to execute `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` option, check if your user meets one of those:
User must own the object, or be a member of the `sysadmin` fixed server role, or the `db_owner` and `db_ddladmin` fixed database roles.

Comment: It works correctly when I add the SET IDENTITY_INSERT right before I execute each statement, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: If the db user has permission to run DB insert then it may be to do with how you're sending the commands from .NET we need your code to advise on this